# How to design a NSDatePicker that looks like Reminder's style?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface

I want to use date picker to select my date, I saw a good style in Reminder,
How do I obtain the style using NSDatePicker. Thanks for helping!

[image]

Comment: Try setting the date pickers `datePickerStyle` field. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDatePickerCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Date_Picker_Style) which describes the different built in styles, which there are three of.

Comment: @BrandonBuck No, that's not the right answer. BTW, Did Anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MacOS 10.15.4, you can set your NSDatePicker's property presentsCalendarOverlay to YES (default is NO).

```
public class YourViewController: NSViewController {
   @IBOutlet var datePicker: NSDatePicker!
   public override func viewDidAppear {
      super.viewDidAppear()
      if #available(OSX 10.15.4, *) {
         self.datePicker.presentsCalendarOverlay = true
      }
   }
}
```